# To load a page when a button is clicked, following selecting a value from a dropdown box

Tags: javascript, html, razor, knockout.js

I have a HTML view page. I have a dropdown box there, from where I can select either of two values: OPEN and CLOSE. After selecting a value from this dropdown box, I need to click on a search button. Based on my value selected from the dropdown box, this click will direct me to another view page. How can I do this?????

Here is my dropdown box and button:

```
<td>
                    <select id="myChoice" class="combo"style="width: 110px; height: 25px">
                        <option value="" class="combo">--Select--</option>
                        <option value="open">OPEN</option>
                        <option value="close">CLOSE</option>
                    </select></td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" style="width: 90px; height: 25px; font-size: 11px" onclick="$root.SearchCustomerProfile">Search</button>
                    </td>
```

Here is my Javascript function:

```
self.SearchCustomerProfile = function () {
    var customer_case = document.getElementById('myChoice').value;

    if ((customer_case) == "open" || (customer_case) == "close")
    {
        window.location.href = '/CustomerProfileSearch';
    }
}
```

Comment: please post what sample of what have you done so far

Comment: Then narrow it down to a simple example allowing to reproduce the problem. And post this simplified example.

Comment: Ok I have edited my post and included the most relevant code snippets. Hope you'll understand from it. Note that after clicking the search button, I want to load the CustomerProfileSearch page.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a little site fixing your problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>get Dropdown Value</title>
        <script>
            window.onload = function(){document.getElementById("button").onclick=
                function() {
                    var e = document.getElementById("select"),
                        txt = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
                if(txt=="--Select--") 
                    return;
                    alert("You clicked " + txt + ". You will be redirected to the " + txt + "-site.");
                    window.location = txt;
                };
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="select">
        <option>--Select--</option>
            <option>OPEN</option>
            <option>CLOSE</option>
        </select>
        <button id="button">SEARCH</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

You have to fire the button-onclick-event and then acces the values of the dropdownlist. This can be done with `document.getElementById("select").options[document.getElementById("select").selectedIndex].text;`

In this example, I gave the dropdownlist the id "select" to acces it with Javascript.

One last very important thing is, that you need to load the entire page before creating the onclick-event. Thats why I'm using "window.onload"

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just need one more thing. I need to add another option: <option>--Select--</option>, which will be the default option in the dropdown list, but selecting it won't redirect. Only if the user selects either OPEN or CLOSE then the redirect occurs.

Comment: Here you go, I added an if-statement and you Select-option.